# ARM template keyvault accesspolicies inside object parameter

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm-template

When i deploy my ARM template for the azure keyvault I got this error message.

```
 "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "An invalid value was provided for 'accessPolicies'."
  }
```

My Template :

```
  {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "name": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "enabledForDeployment": "[parameters('enableVaultForDeployment')]",
                "enabledForDiskEncryption": "[parameters('enableVaultForDiskEncryption')]",
                "enabledForTemplateDeployment": "[parameters('enabledForTemplateDeployment')]",
                "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
                "accessPolicies": [],
                "sku": {
                    "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
                    "family": "A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/add')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "copy": [
                    {
                        "name": "accessPolicies",
                        "count": "[length(parameters('ObjectPolicies'))]",
                        "input": {
                            "tenantId": "[parameters('ObjectPolicies')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].tenantId]",
                            "objectId": "[parameters('ObjectPolicies')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].objectId]",
                            "permissions": {
                                "keys": "[parameters('ObjectPolicies')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].permissions.keys]",
                                "secrets": "[parameters('ObjectPolicies')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].permissions.secrets]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

My Parameter file:

```
  "ObjectPolicies": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "tenantId": "xxxxx",
                    "objectId": "xxxxx",
                    "permissions": {
                        "keys": [
                            "all"
                        ],
                        "secrets": [
                            "all"
                        ]
                    }
                },
```

I want to Create a Keyvault with multiple access policies inside an object to get a good overview inside my parameters. instead of objectID1 , objectId2, objectId 3.
Tried to copy the answer from this Good answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53323673/6351302).
It seems that I have the same setup as 4c74356b41 but still have an error message.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628344/arm-template-key-vault-invalid-value-for-accesspolicies) SO question has also the same error message but he doesn't seem to add an answer to his question.

Comment: hey, what if you remove the second resource ("Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies") temporary? does the error go away? your loop looks fine to me

Comment: The error goes indeed away If I delete the second resource. the second resource came after I placed the loop inside the keyvault resource under accesspolicies I figured out maybe to place the loop inside a new resource bracelet. Maybe this isn't the way to do things at all. But I wanted an efficient way of adding policies to my keyvault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "all" is not supported as a value for the permissions, at least according to the api reference you have to list all of those one by one.

```
"accessPolicies": [
    {
        "tenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "objectId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "permissions": {
            "keys": [
                "encrypt",
                "decrypt",
                "wrapKey",
                "unwrapKey",
                "sign",
                "verify",
                "get",
                "list",
                "create",
                "update",
                "import",
                "delete",
                "backup",
                "restore",
                "recover",
                "purge"
            ],
            "secrets": [
                "get",
                "list",
                "set",
                "delete",
                "backup",
                "restore",
                "recover",
                "purge"
            ],
            "certificates": [
                "get",
                "list",
                "delete",
                "create",
                "import",
                "update",
                "managecontacts",
                "getissuers",
                "listissuers",
                "setissuers",
                "deleteissuers",
                "manageissuers",
                "recover",
                "purge"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/createorupdate#create_a_new_vault_or_update_an_existing_vault

Comment: YES, Totally did the trick. I had the "all" from a previous ARM template where if I remember it good worked like a charm.

Comment: "all" works fine for me. I *did* get the error that OP provided when I tried to grant an access policy against an object from a different tenant, though - that is apparently not allowed.